# include edmx model namespace into class

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net, namespaces, edmx

I am trying to include (using *model_name*;) an ADO.NET entity data model into a .cs file but I can't get the name right. Where do I get the name from? I had problems with this a while ago and now again... Am I supposed to use the model name, entity name, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ADO.NET and sql server using this :

```
Using System.Data;
Using System.Data.sqlclient;
```